# A Littlewood-Paley telescoping sum converges in $L^1$ - how can I prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let  $\psi $ be a radial real-valued $C_c ^\infty$  function supported in the unit open ball, and $\psi(x)=1$ whenever $|x| \leq \frac  1 2$. 
Define $\psi_N (x) = \psi (x/N) - \psi(2x/N)$ where $N = 2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z$, i.e. $N$ is a dyadic number.

Let $f \in \mathcal S$ and let $P_N f $ be its Littlewood-Paley component, that is, $P_N f  = \mathcal F ^{-1} (\psi_N \hat f)$. Also, let $P_{\leq N}f = \mathcal F ^{-1} (\psi _{\leq N} \hat  f)$, where $\psi_{\leq N}(x)= \psi(x/N)$.

How can I prove that $P_{\leq N} f = \sum_{M \leq N} P_M f$ in $L^1$, where $M, N$ are dyadic numbers and $f \in \mathcal S$?
I tried to use Young's inequality, but it does not work for $L^1$ case (although it works for $L^p$ convergence when $p>1$).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as you telescope, all of the terms cancel with each other. The first term in $\sum_{M \leq N}P_M f$ cancels with $P_{\leq N} f$.

as $M$ decreases, the balls on which $\phi$ is supported become arbitrarily small, so that the "$M = -\infty$" term integrates to zero.

Hence they are equal in $L^1$. You would formalise this using a limiting argument.

Comment: @George Dewhirst, How does the $M= -\infty$ term vanish? The Fourier transform does not have a $L^p \to L^1$ type bound as far as I know...

Comment: we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\phi(2^m x))dx = \int_{-\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\delta_0(x)2^{-m} dx = 2^{-m} \to 0$.  We used the substitution $x \to 2^m x$ here. 

The fourier transform of a constant is the dirac delta which integrates to zero once the argument is in the integrals range.